# Verilog simulation of Data Encryption Standard

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, des

I am interested in developing DES (in verilog) for my college project. Can I get help in understanding the simulation results of DES encryption and decryption?

Comment: What do you actually want to know? "Can I get help in understanding" is not really a good question.

Comment: You might want to use an [existing DES core](http://opencores.org/project,des) for comparison/regression testing.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://dhost.info/pasjagor/des/) is an interactive presentation of the various elements in DES, showing each intermediate result for the encryption or decryption of some data and key that you specify yourself. This should help you debug your implementation. There are also test vectors (which help check that your implementation is correct) in various places, e.g. [there](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/bc/des/Des-64-64.test-vectors).